# Javascript selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am a new javascript programmer. having a silly problem. I search everywhere , i think i know everything about it but not clearly that's why code is not working....my code is given below

```
 <input class = "ban_image_new uploadImage" id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/jpeg" name="userfile" />
 <input class = "ban_image_new uploadImage" id="uploadImage2" type="file" accept="image/jpeg" name="userfile" />
 <input class = "ban_image_new uploadImage" id="uploadImage2" type="file" accept="image/jpeg" name="userfile" />
<script>
 $(".uploadImage").change(function(){   

    var file = document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0];     
   // var file2 = $(this).files[0];
    alert(file);

  });

</script>
```

in above code everything is working fine(displaying as object). for variable 'file' ....but not working for 'file2'. As you understand i want to work with class name. So please help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `dom` input element which triggered the change event, this object is referred by `this` in the change handler

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function($){
    $(".uploadImage").change(function () {

        var file = this.files[0];
        // var file2 = $(this).files[0];
        alert(file);

    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6M67d/)

Comment: Thanks a lot to you. But i have  use $(document).ready(function(){})  so do i need   jQuery(function($){})